# Why wont the sunlight affect the mirror?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, mirror, reflection

Why wont the sun light be visible over a mirror object in Cycles?

[image]

Comment: Actually, although the answer shows you how to change the appearance, even not absolute perfect mirrors reflect quite a lot of light... aluminum mirrors reflect around 90% of the visible light spectrum while silver can even reflect up to 98% or 99% for wavelenghts between 350 and 2000 nm. So apart from a dirty or dusty surface, the light streak will hardly be so clearly visible as it is on the wall for example. And since the mirror is not rotated so that it directly reflects the sunlight into the camera, the render result is not so far from reality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sun light affects the mirror just the same as the wall.

The reason you don't see any effect is probably because you have a "perfect mirror" made from a 100% perfectly glossy material.

Generally speaking if you are aiming for realism, you should never have anything in your scene shading wise set to 100%. That includes maximum color saturation, perfect blacks, full whites, maximum glossiness, zero roughness, etc.

If you want to have the sunlight visible in your mirror you have to have a modicum of diffuse component in your shader. Don't make it a full glossy, nor set the roughness to 0.

[image]

Use a *Mix* shader and mix it with a *Diffuse* or *Principled BSDF*, for a small percentage.

[image]

Comment: thanks so much. this information helped me a lot